# Primefaces: How do I get the current sort order in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to get the current sort oder in Java?

Here is an example where cars are sorted by year:

```
<p:column headerText="Year" sortBy="#{car.year}">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
</p:column>
```

By extending `LazyDataModel<T>` it is possible to override the following method:

```
public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Lazy loading is not implemented.");
}
```

but I would like to know how to do this without using a LazyDataModel.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try binding your data table and read it from the bound object?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I have accepted Alex Fire's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jasper de Vries commented you can bind your p:dataTable to a variable in backend:

**facelet**

```
<p:dataTable binding="#{bean.dataTable}" ...>
```

**bean class**

```
private DataTable dataTable;

public DataTable getDataTable() {
   return dataTable;
}

public void setDataTable(DataTable dataTable) {
    this.dataTable = dataTable;
}

public void methodToAccessSortOrder() {
   String sortOrder = this.dataTable.getSortOrder();
   // do anything with sortOrder
}
```

Alternatively you can get your dataTable from the view root by committing the clientId of your datatable:

```
public void methodToAccessSortOrder() {
   DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("<CLIENT ID OF DATATABLE>");
   String sortOrder = dataTable.getSortOrder();
   // do anything with sortOrder
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!